# React app compiles but errors in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've just started building a React.js app with webpack and while the code compiles fine, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'array' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (RoutingContext.js:28)
```

in the browser console. I don't even know where to start with where this issue could be.

The RoutingContext is in react-router's own code not mine, specifically this part:

```
var _React$PropTypes = _react2['default'].PropTypes;
var array = _React$PropTypes.array;
var func = _React$PropTypes.func;
var object = _React$PropTypes.object;
```

The code I think is causing the issue is:

```
render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="adverts" name="adverts" component={Adverts}></Route>
      <Route path="ads" name="ads" component={Adverts}></Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

webpack configuration:

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./index.js"],
  module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
      ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "index.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/(locale)/, /node_modules.+(momentjs)/),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Can you add more details regarding the question? It isn't clear from the sample where the issue is

Comment: @ThisIzKp I'll add my webpack config but I don't know where the issue is either

Comment: but why do you think webpack config might be the issue?

Comment: @ThisIzKp the error is in react-routers own lib

Comment: Do you have prop-types installed?

Comment: @PatrickHund no

Comment: prop-types used to be part of React, now you have to install it separately. The error looks like react-router fails because it's missing. Try `npm install --save-dev prop-types`

Comment: please try to print in console object `_React$PropTypes` and look if `array` property exist in or not, this may be main problem

Comment: @PatrickHund Hmm installed prop-types now to no avail

Comment: @Patrick react-router requires prop-types as its own dependency, you shouldn't need to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using an old version of react-router with a peer dependency of React 15 while using React 16 in your app. React 16 removed PropTypes from the main package, and it looks like react-router is expecting it. Update react-router.